# Get current date Sum of two column and Last Row of one Column using Id - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table A named **patientinfo** as shown:

[image: table A]

and table b named as **tblpayment** is as follows:
[image: table b]

Now, What I want is to get PatientId and PatientName From **Table A** JOINING today's paymentDate of **Table B** and SUM(paymentTotal),SUM(paymentPaid) But LAST row OF paymentRemaining.

In Simple words, I want all the today's patients with SUM of paymentTotal and Sum of paymentPaid but LAST row of paymentRemaining.

Graphically, what I want should be like:

```
patientId   paymentTotal   paymentPaid   paymentRemaining
    252         123500        118500          5000
    253         60000         55000           5000
    254         17500         17500            0
    258         5800            0             5800
```

NOTE: The record should be of current date.

Any Help?

What I have done so far:

```
   SELECT a.patientId , a.patientName, b.paymentTotal , b.paymentPaid , b.paymentRemaining FROM
      patientinfo a
      inner join
      (
      SELECT  patienId , SUM(paymentTotal) as paymentTotal ,SUM(paymentPaid) as paymentPaid,
      MAX(paymentRemaining) as paymentRemaining
      FROM tblpayment WHERE paymentDate LIKE '%$date%' GROUP BY patienId
      )b
      on a.patientId  = b.patienId
```

Everything is fine, But the error in this query is that it gives me the very first value of column paymentRemaining. Whereas, I want the last value of payment and it is giving me the MAX value. What should I replace this Max with?

**EDIT:**

A bit mistake in my question. I don't want MAX of paymentRemaining, but LAST row of paymentRemaining of respective patientId.

Comment: Please, tag one DBMS you really use.Mysql or MS SQL Server.

Comment: Its giving max because you also want max value *In Simple words, I want ...but MAX of paymentRemaining.* right ? your question seems unclear also do provide textual data set instead of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `MIN` instead of `MAX` with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
   t.patientId, 
   b.paymentTotal , 
   b.paymentPaid , b.paymentRemaining 
FROM tblpayment AS t 
LEFT JOIN patientinfo a ON t.patientId = a.patientId
LEFT join
(
   SELECT  patientId , SUM(paymentTotal) as paymentTotal,
     SUM(paymentPaid) as paymentPaid,
     MIN(paymentRemaining) as paymentRemaining
   FROM tblpayment 
  GROUP BY patientId
) b on t.patientId  = b.patientId
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab526c/10)

This will give you exactly what you want:

```
| patientId | paymentTotal | paymentPaid | paymentRemaining |
|-----------|--------------|-------------|------------------|
|       252 |       123500 |      118500 |             5000 |
|       253 |        60000 |       55000 |             5000 |
|       254 |        17500 |       17500 |                0 |
|       258 |         5800 |           0 |             5800 |
```

---

**Update:**

If you want the last row, then it will be the one with the latest date for each patientid. Then try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   t.patientId, 
   b.paymentTotal , 
   b.paymentPaid , 
   t.paymentRemaining 
FROM
(
   a.patientId, paymentRemaining, paymentDate
   FROM tblpayment AS t 
   LEFT JOIN patientinfo a ON t.patientId = a.patientId
) AS t
INNER join
(
   SELECT  patientId , SUM(paymentTotal) as paymentTotal,
     SUM(paymentPaid) as paymentPaid
   FROM tblpayment 
  GROUP BY patientId
) b on t.patientId  = b.patientId
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT patientId, MAX(paymentDate) AS LatestDate
   FROM tblpayment 
   GROUP BY patientId
) AS s ON s.patientId = t.patientId AND t.paymentDate = s.LatestDate
```

Comment: Clear me first. I think using MIN will get me minimum value, not the last row. I need the last row. Am I right?

Comment: @kamranbhatti585 You didn't say that in your answer. What do you mean by the last row??? The query I wrote gives you the exact same results you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry bro. I have edited my question. I don't want MAX of paymentRemaining, but last row value of paymentRemaining. Can you please see the Edited part at the end of question at the end?

Comment: I tried your updated query on the sqlfiddle. But its giving me error on line 9. Can you check that?

Comment: Thank you, your first query worked for me after some changes. :)